# Pass object with List/Set<Object> property to spring controller with json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, controller

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-item-json", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String addItemJson(@ModelAttribute("item") @Valid ItemDTO itemToAdd, BindingResult result,
                                               Model model) {
    //...
}
```

ItemDTO:

```
public class ItemDTO {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String url;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    @ItemUsers
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Ajax request:

```
$.post('/add-item-json', data, function (response) {
                alert("send post request");
            }, 'json');
```

Json:

```
   {
  "url": "www.site.com",
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "user": "aaaa"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "user": "bbbb"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user": "cccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to pass object with List property I get error:

> Exception during execution: Invalid property 'users[0][id]' of
>   bean class [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]: Property referenced in
>   indexed property path 'users[0][id]' is neither an array nor a
>   List nor a Map; returned value was [users{id=null,
>   users='null'}]
>
> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'users[0][id]' of bean class [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]:
>   Property referenced in indexed property path 'users[0][id]' is
>   neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was
>   [users{id=null, users='null'}]

When I try to pass object with Set property I get error:

> Exception during execution: Invalid property 'users[0][id]' of
>   bean class [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]: Illegal attempt to get
>   property 'users' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'users[0][id]' of bean class [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]:
>   Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using
>   property path 'users[0][id]'
>
> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'users[0][id]' of bean class [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]:
>   Illegal attempt to get property 'users' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'users[0][id]' of bean class
>   [com.project.project.dto.ItemDTO]: Cannot get element with index 0
>   from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'users[0][id]'

How can i pass object with Set/List property to spring controller?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: please post your `ItemDTO` class?

Comment: I think you need to use `@RequestBody` and not `@ModelAttribute` as the parameter

Comment: I added ItemDTO. I tried to use @RequestBody and i get an Exception during execution: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: After reading the exception it looks like the exception is coming from method body and is not related to mapping, cause you please insert a breakpoint on first line of `addItemJson` method to confirm it is a mapping issue.

Comment: Yes, exception comes from mapping not from method body.

Comment: the exception is complaining about `ItemDTO.interests` but I don't see interests field in class or JSON object.

Comment: Sorry it is users field

Comment: :) from what you have provided, it should map the users array to List or Set

Comment: Yes, I have tried with Set<User> users and List<User> users.

Comment: But it's not maping(((

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. I still have a problem.

Comment: Something strange with ur error response.. `{id=null, users='null'}` but your json has `{  "id": "1",  "user": "aaaa" }` Notice the plural `users`. Check your `User` Class